# Visual studio for mac - choose android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac, creating Android apps using Xamarin. Whatever I do, VS seems to start a "default" emulator. But I wan't it to use my newly created emulator.

How can I choose emulator, or set a default one?

Previously in XS, there used to be a dropdown selector, it seems to have been removed:

[image: VS Run menu]

More information. I created a fresh project from scratch, when the menu actually appears:

[image: CS run menu present]

Comment: in AVD (android virtual device manager) u have some emulators ? i try it now and i see emulators in dropdown

Comment: Yeah. I used to have it, but not any more, see my updated image, I have two emulators. Doesn't matter if I connect a device either. Must be some setting I've messed up - or a bug. But I don't get the dropdown in XS nor VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had not enabled the android project for BUILD in the build configuration.

To enable it just right click your solution, click options, under Build > Configurations > Configuration Mappings you may enable your android project as shown below.

[image: build cfg]